# Why cloud application's file system is ephemeral

Tags: 12factor

The "Beyond 12 factor APP" and "Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud "(https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html) 
states file system is ephemeral. 
However I got different result when testing with openstack:

1. create VM using openstack server create with centos qcow2 image, no
   external storage
2. ssh to the VM, create file under /home/centos
3. reboot VM
4. after VM startup, the file is still there.

Did I understand something wrong?

quote from the book:

1. cloud-friendly applications don’t just run in the cloud;they embrace
   elastic scalability, **ephemeral filesystems**
2. in the "Logs" chapter: Cloud applications can make no assumptions about the file system on which they run, **other than the fact that it is ephemeral**.

quote from "Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud " :
 *"Avoid Writing to the Local File System": "**Local file system storage is short-lived**."..."When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local files while it is running, **the files will disappear after the application restarts**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is that when running containerized applications you can't trust the file system to be longed lived between restarts, as it may be purged, or you might be running next time on a different instance.

It doesn't mean the data is guaranteed to disappear - just that it isn't guaranteed to stay - very much like a temp folder on a regular server

Comment: Do you mean this is true only for containerized application, but not for VM based application?

Comment: could you please tell a case where data is sure to disappear/purged? Because I tested VM restart, the data is still there.

Comment: it's a concept that means don't assume the file system will remain next time, you can't also assume it will be deleted.
the most common cases where the data will be lost is when you launch the 2nd instance on a different server, or if the storage you use is mounted on a temporary filesystem

Comment: After more reading(openstack documents) and thinking, I think you are right: "It doesn't mean the data is guaranteed to disappear - just that it isn't guaranteed to stay - very much like a temp folder on a regular server"
So it's true cloud native application should embrace ephemeral filesystem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ephemeral(non-persistent) storage is given by default to the guests, if persistent storage is required for the apps, Cinder can be used.

Comment: I created my VM from glance image, without using cinder volume. but data is still there over VM restart.
Does the ephemeral actually mean data will be lost over host failure(VM will be restarted on other host)?
Yes, I understand cinder volume is persistent